# Editing an object from another class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In my program, from the first JFrame (*GUI*) you click a button (labeled *Change Template*) which opens a second JFrame (*TempList*).
There is also a template class.

```
public class Template {
    private String name;

    public Template(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = this.name;
    }
```

**GUI Class**

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static TempList FrameB = null;
    private Template template = new Template("image1");

    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void ChangeTemplateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (FrameB == null) {
            FrameB = new TempList();
        } else {
            if (FrameB.isVisible()) {
              FrameB.hide();
           } else {
              FrameB.show();
           }
        }
    }
```

From TempList, you should  be able to click a button which changes the *name* of the Template object created in *GUI*

What code should I write in the TempList Class so that when a button is pressed, it changes the name of the Template object in the GUI class?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Change Template?    
    this.setVisible(false); //closes Templist
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create `Template` object in `GUI` ? or can it be created in`TempList` ?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and variable names usually not start with a upper case letter to easily differentiate them from class names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setName(...)` on the template. Therefore you need a reference to the `Template` instance you want to change the name of. If you do not have this reference you need to pass it with methods or constructors and so on.

---

A good option (depending on your overall structure) may be to pass it at construction of `TempList`. Therefore change your `TempList` constructor and add an `Template` argument, like here:

```
public class TempList {
    // Member variable to memorize the template for later use
    private Template mTemplate;

    // Constructor with Template argument
    public class TempList(Template template) {
        this.mTemplate = template;
    }

    // Other stuff of TempList
    ...
}
```

Then you can use that reference in your method inside that `TempList` like here:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Change the name
    mTemplate.setName("New Name");

    this.setVisible(false); //closes Templist
}
```

Of course you also need to pass the reference at creation of `TempList` now, take a look at this snippet:

```
private void ChangeTemplateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (FrameB == null){
        // We need to also pass the reference to Template now by using the newly created constructor
        FrameB = new TempList(template);
    } else {
        if (FrameB.isVisible()){
            FrameB.hide();
        } else {
            FrameB.show();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now your `TempList` knows the `Template`, memorizes it inside `mTemplate` and also uses it in his `jButton2ActionPerformed` method.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by [Zabuza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45265176/3992939) is valid. 
Consider also creating a `Template` object in `TempList`, rather than in `Gui`:

```
public class TempList extends JFrame{

    private Template template;
    
    public TempList() {
    
        //todo: JFrame constuction 
        template = new Template("image1");
    }

    public void setTemplateName(String name) {
        template.setName(name);
    }
}
```

Use it in `Gui` by: `FrameB,setTemplateName("new name");`

p.s Stick to Java naming conventions. Use `frameB`